# DataGridViewRowEnter Event on Dynamically create TabPage,Gridview NullReferenceException Was unhandled

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, textbox, tabpage

Here are my variables which are used in below code

```
        int k = 0;
        int k1 = 0;
        int kl = 0;
        TabPage[] tab = new TabPage[10];
        DataGridView[] rtb = new DataGridView[10];
```

Here is my `Tabpage` `GridView` creation based on `TextBox1` enter

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
{
                    k = 0;
                    //s = 0;
                    k = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
                    k1 = k - tabControl2.TabPages.Count;

                    for (int i = 0; i < k1; i++)
                    {
                        tab[i] = new TabPage();

                        //tab[i] = new TabPage();
                        rtb[i] = new DataGridView();
                        //Start Gridview
                        rtb[i] = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
                        rtb[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 50);
                        rtb[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1020, 150);
                        //ID Column
                        rtb[i].Columns.Add("tr_id", "ID");
                        rtb[i].Columns["tr_id"].ReadOnly = true;
                        rtb[i].Columns["tr_id"].Width = 1;
                        //rtb[i].Columns["tr_id"].ReadOnly = true;

                        rtb[i].Columns.Add("Counter", "SNo");
                        rtb[i].Columns["Counter"].ReadOnly = true;

                        rtb[i].Columns["tr_id"].ReadOnly = true;
                        rtb[i].Columns["tr_id"].Width = 10;

                        // Color Column
                        rtb[i].Columns.Add("color_name", "Color Name");
                        rtb[i].Columns["color_name"].ReadOnly = true;
                        rtb[i].Columns.Add("color_no", "Pantone No.");
                        rtb[i].Columns["color_no"].ReadOnly = true;

                        //End Gridview

                        tab[i].Controls.Add(rtb[i]);
                        tab[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 22);
                        tab[i].Name = "tab" + i.ToString();
                        tab[i].Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
                        tab[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 242);
                        tab[i].Text = "Article" + i.ToString();
                        tab[i].UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
                        tabControl2.TabPages.Add(tab[i]);

                        //MessageBox.Show(""+tab[i].Text);

                        rtb[i].RowEnter += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView_RowEnter);      
}
```

Now here is my `GridviewRowEnter` event

```
private void dataGridView_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
            try
            {
                kl = 0;
                kl = Convert.ToInt32(tabControl2.TabPages.Count);

                for (int i = 0; i < kl; i++)
                {
                    //var rtb = new DataGridView();
                    for (int j = 0; j < rtb[i].Rows.Count; j++)
                    {
                        rtb[i].Rows[j].Cells[0].Value = j + 1;
                    }
                }
                kl = 0;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
}
```

I enter some data into `TextBox` 2 and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then 2 `TabPages` and `GridViews` Created and `DataGridViewRowEnter` event work correctly.

After that I'm entering some data on `Gridview` it works, it generates a serial number on `Column1` but when I need one more `TabPage` and `GridView` I go to the `TextBox` and rub 2 and type 3 and `Enter` it creates one more without my data loss but this time my event show `Exception` that shown here:

[image]

> Also Click Here
>   http://s21.postimg.org/u8dlj7itz/Untitled.jpg

Comment: Please post the **text** of the exception - I cannot read anything on that screenshot (way too small)

Comment: NullReferenceException Was unhandled
Object reference not set an instance of an object
on Event where count gridview rows

Comment: @marc_s i give you exception and link where image show correctly